# For Google Sheets, hiding rows based on empty cell (cell has a formula)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script someone wrote to hide rows based on a checkbox, which I got working. I'm trying to modify it to hide rows based on an empty cell. But it won't work. I'd actually like it to start looking from A23 down.

Here's the modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const shts=['Main'];
  if(shts.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1 && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=="") {
    sh.hideRows(Number(e.range.rowStart));
    e.source.toast('Row ' + e.range.rowStart + ' has been hidden.');
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const shts=['Main'];//only works in these sheet names
  if(shts.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1 && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart>22 && e.range.getDisplayValue().length==0) {
    sh.hideRows(e.range.rowStart);
  }  
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Maybe it doesn't register as empty since the empty cells have formulas in them.

Comment: Try it this way.